NLCD pixel area measurements are larger than my areas of interest
I was having trouble calculating the volume of grasslands in subbasins, because whereas grasses appeared to be 50% on the map, when I multiplied the cell counts by 900 the products were sometimes larger than the entire subbasin. I started all over with a new project, loaded [Albers Conical Equal Area] NLCD raster in [EPSG 4326] project, fudged around with raster layers [EPSG 5070], compared Zonal Stat cell counts to pixel counts to Raster Calculator $Area results, tried reprojecting raster (denied), but nothing was lining up. I graphed various results, but I can't get a linear relationship.
So, I started over again and I loaded the NLCD raster per above. I then went to the local HS football field in GoogleHybred, turned on the NLCD layer, used the Measure Area to outline an adjacent pixel, and then turned off the layer. The pixel is clearly larger than 30x30m (900m2). In fact, it's closer to 1360m2 based on the polygon I drew. So, I see why my big data are so wrong, but I don't know how to fix this problem and regain my faith in QGIS area calculations.
I have attached a few screenshots for reference.


Run your analyses in the native CRS of the NLCD raster, not 4326
